# Can we get data from database using [HttpPost] & insert data into database using [HttpGet] in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, http-verbs

Can we do update operation using [HttpsGet] ?
I am bit confused on this because I am new in coding. Can anybody help me on this to clear the concept?

Comment: HTTP verbs have nothing to do with data access. Yes, you can write in a GET and read in a POST if that makes sense, as long as you write the appropriate code.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Should you do it? No

Comment: POST is used both in SOAP and GraphQL to *query* for example, and even other protocols to send complex query data in the body. In fact, most web site forms use POST even when they don't change data.

Comment: Here's a good post for best practices: https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/

Comment: @insane_developer That's for a REST API. Not everything follows the REST pattern. And even then, you have exceptions. For example, a GET request typically doesn't mutate state, but you might also insert a record into the database to record that a record has been accessed for auditing purposes. It's important to distinguish between what the framework will allow you to do, whether the pattern you're trying to follow allows it, and whether there's any exceptions to those general guidelines.

Comment: thank you for your comments @insane_developer . If we can get data using [HttpPost] then in MVC why it throws error if we have only one action method(for an example - Index) in Home controller and declare it with [Httppost]?

       [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
             return View("Index");
        }

This throws error but if we put [HttpGet]. it works. why?

Comment: hi @mason, can you please help to clear the concept in ASP.NET MVC point of view?

Comment: @ali in order for that to work, you would need to do a post, from a form in another page that points to Index. The browser is certainly not going to do that for you.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC provides action methods - and you can code your action method to do anything you want regardless of the HTTP Verb that's used. Now if you're trying to follow a particular pattern (such as REST) then adherence to the pattern means you wouldn't mutate state, but even then there's exceptions, such as the auditing I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is nothing that would prevent you from doing an update operation with on an HttpGet request within ASP.NET MVC. There's also nothing that prevents you from returning data from the database in response to an HttpPost.

Certain patterns would recommend you avoid doing that, but there is nothing in the framework that would prevent it.